# Responsive background image in bootstrap container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using multiple containers so I can have unique transparent image in them.

I want the background image in them to be responsive and to keep ratio, I found a lot of suggestions to put `background-size: cover;` but it doesn't work for me. I can't get the image to be responsive.

what I've tried:

```
  object-fit: contain;    
  -webkit-background-size: cover;     
  -moz-background-size: cover;    
  -o-background-size: cover;    
  background-size: cover;            
  flex: 1;
```

css code:

```
 .container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

 .container1::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(bg2.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  object-fit: contain;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1; 
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container container1">
<p> some text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: where is HTML ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I update my post with html.

Comment: with bootstrap you don't have to set up the css to be responsive for the image. You can use a pre-defined Bootstrap class called `img-responsive` for the div that contains the image. [Check out this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)

Comment: not in bootstrap4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the same image to scale based on the size of the browser window then here is the code.

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Do not set width, height, or margins.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.  My css code:     `content: "";
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1; 
     background-image:url('bg2.jpg');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:contain;
     background-position:center;
     opacity: 0.2;`

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: There is so many other ways to do this aswell, You can try other techniques in your free time

Comment: Once again thanks, I almost gave up from this, now I see that in my first try i should use     `background-size: contain;` ,  instead of     `background-size: cover;`.